Can we use Jest with @web/test-runner to use features like spying and mocking?
I'm currently developing web components with Lit and using @web/test-runner along with @open-wc/testing for writing unit tests. According to the documentation on Test Frameworks: Write Your Own, is there a method to integrate Jest for the spying and mocking features, while still using @web/test-runner for execution? How can this be achieved?
There are some solutions like using Sinon or Jasmin or Chai f.e for spying, but I was wondering if I can use Jest for its features.

Yes, you can use Jest's mocking and spying features in conjunction with @web/test-runner for test execution.
Maybe I wonder if you've already create a jest setup file and a setup file for @web/test-runner or not.
Anyway let me offer how to write tests using Jest Mocks and @web/test-runner.


import { fixture, expect } from '@open-wc/testing';
import { html } from 'lit';
import './your-component.js';

describe('your-component', () => {
  it('calls a mocked function', async () => {
    const yourMock = jest.fn();
    const element = await fixture(html`<your-component></your-component>`);
    element.yourFunction = yourMock;

    // Trigger the function
    element.someMethodThatCallsYourFunction();

    // Assert that the mock function was called
    expect(yourMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});



And you know, you can execute your tests using @web/test-runner as a last step.
Good luck with your coding.

Thanks for your response. Did the same, but I had this error:
ReferenceError: jest is not defined
